How does the axiom of infinity allow us to conclude that $\{ 3,5,9 \}$ exists here? (Tao's Analysis I)
I am wondering why after defining the following axiom

Axiom 3.8 (Infinity). There exists a set $\mathbf{N}$, whose elements are called natural numbers, as well as an object 0 in $\mathbf{N}$, and an object $n++$ assigned to every natural number $n \in \mathbf{N}$, such that the Peano axioms (Axioms 2.1-2.5) hold.

we can conclude that the set $\{ 3,5,9\}$ exists. This is from Tao's Analysis I, and he explains that this axiom allows to conclude the existence of that set; the reason why I don't follow his reasoning is that I don't see how the fact that there exists a model of the naturals implies that the specific set we canonically use for the naturals, $\{ 1,2,3, \ldots \}$, exists, as the model of the naturals which exists may use a completely different set. Here are the exact words Tao uses, right after defining axiom 3.8 (infinity), to reason this:

From the axiom of infinity we see that numbers such as 3,5 , and 7 are indeed objects in set theory, and so (from the pair set axiom and pairwise union axiom) we can indeed legitimately construct sets such as $\{3,5,9\}$ as we have been doing in our examples.

Earlier in this chapter Tao informally defined a  set to be a collection of objects, so it seems that Tao's reasoning is that axiom 3.8 (infinity) tells us that $\{ 1,2,3,\ldots \} $ exists, and because a set is a collection of objects, $ x \in \{ 1,2,3,\ldots \}$ implies that $x$ is an object, so things like $3,5,9$ are each objects, and because Tao had as axioms that for any object $a$, $\{ a \}$ exists, and that the union of $2$ sets exists as a set, we conclude the set $\{ 3,5,9 \}$ exists. I just don't see how axiom 3.8 implies that $\{ 1,2,3,\ldots \} $ exists, if Tao's reasoning indeed meant to use this fact. Perhaps the following axiom would be useful  to show that $\{ 1,2,3,\ldots \} $ exists:

Axiom 3.7 (Replacement). Let $A$ be a set. For any object $x \in A$, and any object $y$, suppose we have a statement $P(x, y)$ pertaining to $x$ and $y$, such that for each $x \in A$ there is at most one $y$ for which $P(x, y)$ is true. Then there exists a set $\{y: P(x, y)$ is true for some $x \in A\}$, such that for any object $z$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
z \in\{y & : P(x, y) \text { is true for some } x \in A\} \\
& \Longleftrightarrow P(x, z) \text { is true for some } x \in A .
\end{aligned}
$$

The axiom of replacement seems like it could be useful to "translate" from one model of the naturals to another- but I couldn't see an exact way to do this. I tried using the fact that if another model of the naturals exists, it would have bijection with the model we know exists to get a means of "translation" between models using the bijective function, but realized that this was assunmong what we wanted to prove, as the fact that there exists a model using $\{ 1,2,3, \ldots \}$ as the set of naturals assumes that the set $\{ 1,2,3, \ldots \}$ exists.  So what gives us the justification to conclude sets like $\{ 3,5,9\}$ exist right after defining Axiom 3.8 here?

Do you have that subsets of sets are sets? Then once you have that $\mathbb{N}$ exists, then ${3, 5, 9} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ exists too.

@K.Jiang we do have that axiom; but how do we know that ${ 1,2,3, \ldots }$ specifically exists? We just know that some model of the naturals exists by axiom 3.8, right?

Are you saying that even though you know there exists a $\mathbb{N}$, you don't know that its elements are called $1,2,3,\ldots$ ?  I would say that in this context, 1,2,3,... are defined to be the elements of $\mathbb{N}$.  Otherwise, do you have another definition of 1,2,3,... in mind?

Tao is here neglecting to mention the "standard construction" of the set $\mathbf{N}$; in Set Theory, we construct the naturals by declaring $0$ to be the empty set, and then "inductively" defining $1 = \{0\}, 2 = \{1, 0\}, n + 1 = \{0, 1, ... , n\}$. What the Axiom of Infinity "actually" says is that there is an inductive set: an inductive set is a set containing the empty set that is closed under successor, which is the operation $(\cdot)^+$ that Tao mentions informally (set-theoretically, the successor $x^+$ is the set $x \cup \{x\}$, which as you can verify gives us $0^+ = \varnothing^+ = \{\varnothing\} = 1$ etc.). So under this labeling scheme $\mathbf{N}$ does exist (it is the smallest inductive set, which is the intersection of the set of inductive sets); once you have this, you can use the Comprehension Schema to obtain $\{3, 5, 9\}$. If we don't give the natural numbers a set-theoretic ontology, then it indeed does not follow that the set of natural numbers "actually exists". The labeling scheme that I mentioned (which is due to von Neumann) is one way to do so, but the fact that all Peano systems are isomorphic tells us that they are all, at least structurally, the same.
